# How can I turn a torch tensor into a list of numpy arrays in Pytorch?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, torchvision

I have a torch tensor that looks like torch.Size([32, 3, 64, 64]).

I'm trying convert the tensor into something that can pass these assertions:

```
assert(type(images) == list)
assert(type(images[0]) == np.ndarray)
assert(len(images[0].shape) == 3)
assert(np.max(images[0]) > 10)
assert(np.min(images[0]) >= 0.0)
```

I'm currently doing this to convert the tensor:

```
# turn tensor into list of lists
imgs = imgs.tolist()

# iterate over list and turn each image into a numpy array with normalized values
for idx, img in enumerate(imgs):
  img = cv2.normalize(np.array(img), None,
  alpha = 0, beta = 255, norm_type = cv2.NORM_MINMAX )
```

and I get this error:

```
File "scripts/run_model.py", line 158, in get_inception_score
assert(type(images[0]) == np.ndarray)
AssertionError
```

How can I convert the tensor correctly so that type(images) is a list and type(images[0] is a np.ndarray)?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Convert Pytorch tensor to numpy array first using `tensor.numpy()` and then convert it into a list using the built-in `list()` method.

```py
images = torch.randn(32,3,64,64)
numpy_imgs = images.numpy()
list_imgs = list(numpy_imgs)
print(type(images))
print(type(numpy_imgs))
print(type(list_imgs))
print(type(list_imgs[0]))
```

> <class 'torch.Tensor'>
>
> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>
> <class 'list'>
>
> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>